код php не работает
почему когда я ввожу php artisan serve
потом командная строка выводит мне это:
WARN  Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?).


Может ваш случай

Возможно, у вас уже что-то висит на порту 8000 и поэтому сервер не может стартовать

Если вы на Windows - исправьте в вашем php.ini значение variables_order.
Должно быть
variables_order = "GPCS"

Альтернативный способ
Запустите сервер командой:
php -S localhost:8000 -t public

Но я бы рекомендовал использовать что-нибуть типа XAMPP

Извините, а не могли бы вы пояснить, каким образом variables_order связана с запуском встроенного сервера? И чем поможет запуск на том же самом порту, который определённо занят?

А с чего вы взяли, что порт занят? В ошибке говориться о невозможности запустить сервер, не более того.

С того, что я мало-мало говорить по-английски. И немного понимаю, что на самом деле написано в сообщении об ошибке.

Я, к сожалению, даже мало-мало не говорю, но если порт запнят, лара выдает другое сообщение
WARN  Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use).

Принимается. Тем не менее, тупо копировать ответы из английского раздела не понимая их смысла всё равно не стоит.
